# Printing Arabic string usin Sewoo Lk-p41 Printer?

Tags: android, printing, utf-8, bluetooth, arabic

I have a Sewoo Lk-p41 Printer, I have connected it to my android app using Bluetooth and it worked for printing English String, now I have to print Arabic String and it prints a question marks instead.
I have tried this and still not working!

```
byte ptext[] = toPrint[i].getBytes("UTF-8"); 
value = new String(ptext, "UTF-8");
cpclPrinter.printCPCLText(0, 4, 0, 25, 50, value, 0);
```

Comment: The question marks will indicate that the font being used by the printer does not contain glyphs for those characters.  You will need to either 1) select a font the printer has which has glyphs for those characters; 2) download such a font to the printer; or 3) print the page as an image.

Comment: I've tried all the fonts on the printer, and I don't wont to load a new font on the printer so that my app can work with other printers. do you have any idea on how to make my string as an image ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this awesome lib, it has solved Arabic issues in Bluetooth printing.

https://github.com/mazenrashed/Printooth

You can use it by:

```
var printables = ArrayList<Printable>()
var printable = Printable.PrintableBuilder()  
    .setText("عربي") //The text you want to print
.setCharacterCode(USE ARABIC INCODING HERE) // Character code to support languages
.setNewLinesAfter(1) // To provide n lines after sentence
.build()
printables.add(printable)
BluetoothPrinter.printer().print(printables)
```